# Rendering Microsoft wavetable output with Reaper

Tags: recording, daw, reaper

I've recorded a part-audio part-midi project in Reaper on a PC. The midi goes to the MS wavetable synth on the PC. I'm using a Focusrite 18i20 USB unit.
I can hear the wavetable output in monitoring, but not in rendering. I'm looking for a solution, so I can render the track using the wavetable synth as the midi device.

I've seen a post on this elsewhere, without a solution, but it is old, and maybe things have moved forward.

One possibility is to route the wavetable synth sound down the output channels from the DAW, loop it back via a stereo cable on the 18i20 to one of the DAW inputs, and record it as an audio track.
However, that doesn't seem a very elegant solution, as the digitised sound is already in the computer, and Reaper can get its hands on it for monitoring, so why not for rendering?

Maybe it is because the wavetable synth can only work in real-time, whereas the rendering is a non-real-time mathematical operation.

So, assuming rendering it is impossible, is it possible to get the wavetable synth output as an input to an audio track in Reaper without looping back via the external device?

One suggestion is Virtual Audio Cable (http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm). Inexpensive but not free.

I could sidestep the problem by using a VST midi sound generator to replace the wavetable synth. Any decent free ones? I'm only really looking for percussion sounds.

Has anyone solved the MS wavetable synth problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late (5 years...) but I recommend Voicemeeter as a free virtual cable, I think that is included in; while as a free sound generator there are Independence of Magix and maybe Halion SE (from Steinberg) and Kontakt (from Native Insturments).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although it is a bit late! I've been using a human drummer recently; I never did find decent midi drum tracks (for jazz). I started using Voicemeeter a couple of months ago for online music teaching, and I think it would do the job. I haven't actually tried this old scenario.